what's the best way to translate texts in images png without altering anything else and I have tried ocr websites and the translation is no sense
this diagram for exemple
I tried Ocr websites,I tried converting it to pdf then word ,about to try with paint but its going to take me a shitload of time so I am only trying to translate the text on the image and nothing else has to change from the design

@KJ How does that relate to the OP's question about how to perform OCR on their PNG image?

@KJ The OP says they have a PNG image. What is your insistence on converting it to PDF?

When a PDF has an image with text. What you see on the surface is pixels and the text is in effect invisible plain text overlay, without any tabs or other positional info. EXCEPT, where the line starts and its voids in offset space values to next character.
Thus If we presume the source is say "True Blue English" as enforced here, then any "Red" translation cannot be expected to be aligned except by its first character.
So the obvious problem is the pixels are English, whilst the "Read Aloud" audio text is all Greek to me but will be audio garbage to any Greek reader.

If you try to use Words own OCR direct the "Problems" are different but the results are often just as poor. The word by word translator cannot understand many odd human concepts such as concatination.



In summary the Translation must be done BEFORE convert to PNG or PDF or DOCX.
